# Baby Crested Gecko Isn't Eating

Tags: geckos

I adopted a crested gecko (it's around 3 months old) and have been trying to feed the powder fruit diet (Rapashys) and have had no luck. I've broke twice and went and got crickets and calcium dusted (trust me, I don't like that I did it either) them to hold him over in hope that he would eventually take to the food but have yet to have any luck. Any advice?

Comment: Can you give me info on your setup?

Comment: @RebeccaRVT sure, right now i just have a 5 gallon aquariam (not vertical, and yeah, i know it should be vertical). I have the Zilla Jungle Mix for bedding, a few pieces of cork bark and some fake vines throughout the tank.

Comment: What are the temps?

Comment: @RebeccaRVT normally around 75ish F.